# whm - disable email routing on same server?

Tags: email, routing

I believe I saw a setting somewhere once where I could disable WHM from routing emails to other email accounts on the same server. Does anyone know where that might be?

Reason for this is my main email is on Google Apps, so when users from the same server email me they go to the mailbox on the server. I'd prefer when users email they lookup the MX queries every time.

Anyone help me out?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under "DNS Functions", click "Edit MX Entry", and select the correct zone. Pick "Remote Mail Exchanger", and make sure that the MX entries are correct.